# How to control/override notifications being sent by NSTableView/NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am wondering how I can override the notification being sent when the selection within a `NSOutlineView` | `NSTableView` has been changed. What I need to achieve is to add userInfo data to the notification being sent out.

I know that `outlineViewSelectionDidChange` of a `NSOutlineView` can be used to send out a custom notification like this:

```
func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSOutlineView.selectionDidChangeNotification, object: self, userInfo: ["test": 1])
}
```

However, when I connect an observer to this notification ...

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(onSelectSetViewController(_:)),
            name: NSOutlineView.selectionDidChangeNotification,
            object: nil
        )
```

... , I receive this as an output:

```
@objc
    private func onSelectSetViewController(_ notification: Notification) {
        print(notification)
    }
```

> name = NSOutlineViewSelectionDidChangeNotification, object = Optional(), userInfo = Optional([AnyHashable("test"): 1])
>
> name = NSOutlineViewSelectionDidChangeNotification, object = Optional(), userInfo = nil

So the notification is being sent twice. How can I avoid this and sent out a notification with userInfo data only once?

Comment: "So the notification is being sent twice."  That's because you are observing a notification when you don't have to?

Comment: Post your own custom notification instead of `NSOutlineView.selectionDidChangeNotification`? Only listen to notifications sent by one specific object? What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's an aesier solution.

Comment: I have mentioned already what I want to achieve: "What I need to achieve is to add userInfo data to the notification being sent out." The userInfo contains data being retrieved from an internal data container that is changing continuously and asynchronously. Therefore, I want to have the userInfo stored in the notification to guarantee race conditions. However, I find it not very elegant that every time the user changes the selection, the view is emitting notifications twice, first without userInfo, second with userInfo. I fear that filtering is the only choice I have.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the name of your forwarding notification to something else and your notification will be sent only once. Then add an observer to listen to the forwarding notification. That will solve your problem:

```
func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MySelectionDidChangeNotification, object: self, userInfo: ["test": 1])
}
```

Then add this observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(onSelectSetViewController(_:)),
            name: MySelectionDidChangeNotification,
            object: nil
        )
```

Comment: That's unnecessary and pointless since table view and outline view each comes with the selection notification through its delegate.

Comment: @El Tomato That depends on what the OP wants to do. That would be true if the OP wants to use that notification without any additional data. Apparently, the OP wants to add additional info, and that is why a forwarding notification could be justifiable.